# Disable switching tabs after long press on UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I want to disable `UITabBarViewController`'s ability to switch to long pressed `UITabBarItem` at specific `tag`.

What I tried is

1. subclassed `UITabBarViewController`as `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`
2. added  `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and set it's `delegate` to `self`
3. overriden `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` and made it to return `NO`

But it didn't work.

Mind you that I already have `UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer` added to one of the `UITabBarItem` like this:

```
[self.tabBar.subviews[2] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer]
```

And it works fine. I would love to just disable recognizing long pressing and fire `UITapGestureRecognizer` instantly, even while long pressing.

Thanks

Comment: you can directly turn off user interaction, by setting UITabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
 and to enable it use UITabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
on any button click. No need of Gesture recogniser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                             initWithTarget:self 
                                             action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
        longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

and in the handle long press method

```
-  (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender { 
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
      NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
    //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:0]setEnabled:FALSE];
     }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
       NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.");
   //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
     }
  }
```

Make your `AppDelegate` a `UITabBarControllerDelegate`, in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` call

```
   UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    tabBarController.delegate = (id)self;
```

and add this method:

```
 - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController; 
{    
       if (viewController.restorationIdentifier isEqualToString:@"foo")
           return YES;
       else
           return NO;
}
```

Comment: I missed the ` shouldSelectViewController: ` method, but you forgot to mention that it should be added in `AppDelegate `. Anywas, that did exactly what I needed, thanks